# Functor of Compactly Generated Spaces Right Adjoint

Tags: general-topology

Let consider the subcategory $kTop \subset Top$ of compactly generated spaces. Obviously we have two functors:

$j: kTop \to Top $ , the canonical embedding functor and

$k: Top \to kTop, T \mapsto k(T)$ , which endows $T$ with topology of compactly generated spaces.

Here for topology of compactly generated spaces is defined as follows:

$U \subset X$ open if and only if $s^{-1}U \subset K$ open for all locally compact spaces $K$ and continuous $s:K \to X$.

My question is: Why is $k$ right adjoint to $j$,so why for all $X \in kTop$ and $Y \in Top$ we have bijection $Hom_{Top}(j(X), Y) \cong Hom_{kTop}(X, k(Y)) $?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it is based on a different definition of compactly generated spaces.

Comment: What is your definition of locally compact spaces in the absence of separation axioms? And don’t you mean compact (Hausdorff) instead of locally compact as in your other question on this subject?

Comment: drhab: Which definition? Do you mean the following one: The CG topology of $X$ has following universal property: A map $t:X \to T$ is continuous iff for all local compact $K$ and continuous $s:K \to X$ the maps $t \circ s$ are continuous? In this case I think say that this definition of CG topology is equivalent to mine which I explained above.